# Confirm Password Not Working In MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am using MVC database first approach. My database is not having Confirm password field. So I have added this field in the partial class which I created and used `[NotMapped]` attribute.

Database generated class

```
namespace OnlineTest
{        

    public partial class User
    {

        public User()
        {

            this.tbl_purchase = new HashSet<Purchase>();
        }

        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Purchase> tbl_purchase { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Partial class which I created

```
namespace OnlineTest
{

    [MetadataType(typeof(UserMetadata))]
    public partial class User
    {

        [DataType("Password")]
        [NotMapped]
        [System.Web.Mvc.Compare("password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserMetadata
    {

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please type a username")]
        [Display(Name = "UserName")]
        public string username { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please type a EmailId")]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "E-mail is not valid")]
        [Display(Name = "Email address")]
        public string email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please type a Phone number")]
        [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
        [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = "Your mobile not corrct")]
        [RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9]*)", ErrorMessage = "You have to enter only numbers 111-111-1111")]
        public string PhoneNo { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please type a password")]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string password { get; set; }
    }        
}
```

View for Compare password

```
<div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, htmlAttributes: new 
               { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

But for some reason, it is not working and Model.state is not valid it is throwing error "The password and confirmation password do not match."

Comment: The easiest way to check it: set a beakpoint inside the action to compare

Comment: @HappyCoding I didn't write any method to compare. This is the procedure I found on internet plzz guide me, If I need to add something.

Comment: Do you ask user to enter the Password in your view too? Where in your code the Password property value is assigned?

Comment: @FeryalBadili I have edited the que have addec the password part too I just wrote the ConfirmPassword because my question was on ConfirmPassword

Comment: Can anyone plzz help me with this?

Comment: Did you try this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931103/dataannotation-to-compare-two-properties

Comment: Also look at "Snehal Thakkar" answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4938078/using-dataannotations-to-compare-two-model-properties

Comment: @FeryalBadili I have done the exact same thing but it is not working cannot understand why.