# How can I get DataAnnotations.Compare to compare properties from 2 different objects?

Tags: c#, compare, data-annotations

I'm getting an error using the view below

> The property Models.m_Join.Member.password could not be found.

The 'Password' field that the error refers to is part of the 'member' object that is in the m_Join model.

I've tried using : -

```
    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("member.password", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.errors), ErrorMessageResourceName = "passwordsDontMatch")]

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("member_password", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.errors), ErrorMessageResourceName = "passwordsDontMatch")]
```

But neither of them work.

```
public class m_Join
{

    public Member member { get; set; }

    [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Compare("password", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.errors), ErrorMessageResourceName = "passwordsDontMatch")]
    public string passwordConfirm { get; set; }


}
```

What do I have to use to get the code to compare member.password and passwordConfirm

Edit: The 2 properties I want to compare are in different objects. The properties in the proposed duplicate question are in the same object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataAnnotation to compare two properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931103/dataannotation-to-compare-two-properties)

Comment: @LukaszBalazy No, read my question! The 2 properties I want to compare are in different objects. The properties in your question are in the same object

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create a method for this, that would assign both values to the string, and then compare them and return you a boolean as a result?

Comment: No, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: First you should try CompareAttribute.
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.compareattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2
You have topic about how to use it to compare password here -> 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21931103/dataannotation-to-compare-two-properties